# Layout large amount of Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, text

so i've got about 100 pages with different Text-Layouts. Bold Fonts in large paragraphs, italic, headlines etc .pp.

Now i'm wondering whats the best way to display them in my uiview. i cannot find an element that fits for me (UILable, Textfield, etc).

Whats the best way to do this? any ideas?

thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: shure. thought there were better options. i played a bit with TTStyledText in three20

Answer (score 0):

If the load time is really long, you should take a look at `CATiledLayer`. It is used (most probably) on Safari.app or Maps.app to load information on screen lazily

Answer (score 0):

In a company I worked for, they use the [cocos2d framework](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) to render interactive books, with funky fonts. It may be a bit too much for what you need, but as choise said, you could use a UIWebView